Can't configure Python interpreter on Eclipse/Pydev on a Mac
I am trying to configure the python interpreter on a Mac for an Eclipse project using Eclipse/PyDev without success.
When I create a simple project (Hello World) to test things out, PyDev wants me to configure the Python interpreter. I am using pyenv to manage python versions (I need this for debugging the SALT application). When I specify /Users/dnessett/.pyenv/shims/python or /Users/dnessett/.pyenv/shims/python3.10, I get the following error message from PyDev:
"Unable to get info on the interpreter <followed by the path I specified to either .../shims/python or .../shims/python3.10>
Common reasons include:
.
.
.
-Specifying an invalid interpreter
(usually a link to the actual interpreter on Mac or linux"
I looked in /Users/dnessett/.pyenv/shims and neither python nor python3.10 are soft links to another file. So, I don't understand how to properly specify the interpreter.
Note that when I click the "new" button on Preferences/Python Interpreters window, I get a drop down list containing several choices, the first of which is "Browse for Python/pypy exec" (all other choices are not applicable) I select this and it brings up a file finder window, which doesn't include hidden files starting with ".". So, I cancel this browser window and enter the Python interpreter info manually, which includes a name and the path to the interpreter, specified above. It is when I click "OK" on this window that I get the message specified above.

OK. I figured out the problem. I forgot to execute pyenv global 3.10.15. Once I did that, Eclipse/PyDev accepted the interpreter.

Please accept your own answer and remove the prefix {Solved} from the title of your question instead.

I should also remark that if using a virtual environment, going to that environment and executing pyenv local 3.10.15 will also solve the problem (for that environment only).
